# Dynamically added spinners are empty

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dynamic, spinner

So I have an activity in my app that dynamically adds and removes fields and by default, there is one field already there. The original spinner contains all the information in it and I can select any object in there, however, the dynamically added spinners are empty. How would I dynamically add a populated spinner? I tried messing around with calling a populating method in the addField method but that didn't help and made things weirder. Here is how it looks like when I add new fields: [image]

here is the method that adds fields:

```
public void addField(View v) {
        if(parentLayout.getChildCount() < maxCourses) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
            //add new row before add field button
            parentLayout.addView(rowView, parentLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No more than " + maxCourses + " courses\ncan be taken per semester", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and here is how I call it through a button "ADD COURSE"

```
addFieldBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_field_btn);
        addFieldBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addField(v);
            }
        });
```

Here is the field.XML code for newly generated fields, they share the same ID as the original, populated field

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/colorSecondaryDark"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/first_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove_field_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorSecondary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="removeField"
        android:text="REMOVE\nCOURSE"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If anyone can give me some tips or help, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: why you dont use adapter for it .if you use adapter you can remove/add items from/to adapter's list.

Comment: Did you added adapter to your spinners?

Comment: check https://demonuts.com/android-spinner-custom-adapter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new spinners don't know where to get the data. You should set an adapter to each of the new spinners.
Like here:

```
public void addField(View v) {
    if(parentLayout.getChildCount() < maxCourses) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
        Spinner spinner = rowView.findViewById(R.id.first_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = getAnAdapterForThatSpinner();
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
        //add new row before add field button
        parentLayout.addView(rowView);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No more than " + maxCourses + " courses\ncan be taken per semester", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```